# How to check if the query string is null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am querying a table using C# and produce the following SQL line:

```
'det.aspx?ObjectID=' + CAST(CT.OBJECTID AS VARCHAR) + '&cid=45&fid=' + ISNULL(CAST(CT.A0900 AS VARCHAR), '') 'TD'
```

produces:

```
http://localhost:3652/Pages/det.aspx?ObjectID=1092648&cid=45&fid=
```

I am trying to get the value for `fid` ONLY if it is not null OR if there is a value:

```
if (Request.QueryString["fid"] != null || Request.QueryString["fid"].Length > 0)
{
    string t = Request.QueryString["fid"];
}
```

Using the example above, it should not enter the `if` caluse, but it is.

How can I resolve it.

Comment: Given what you have, the only way it would enter your if block is if `fid` is not null, so it must not be null.

Comment: You're checking `Request.QueryString["fid"].Length > 0`, but in your sample URI it is `&fid=`, so the length is 0.

Comment: can you change the code to check if `if(! IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["fid"]))`

Comment: if( ! Request.QueryString["fid"].IsNullOrEmpty() )  ?

Comment: Is it null or DBNull? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your query to this: (use a `case` statement inside it)

```
'det.aspx?ObjectID=' + CAST(CT.OBJECTID AS VARCHAR) + '&cid=45'+

case when CT.A0900 is not null then '&fid='+CAST(CT.A0900 AS VARCHAR)
else '' end
```

Comment: Can I keep the `if` statement?

Comment: for the `if (Request.QueryString["fid"] != null || Request.QueryString["fid"].Length > 0)` statement now, I get the following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: the "case" inside a query  plays the role of "if"

Comment: also when you can easily handle it with the SQL query then I think it's not need to handle it in application layer

Answer (score 1):

When checking for a null or empty string, use the built-in .NET string method of [string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) or [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["fid"]) )
{
    string t = Request.QueryString["fid"];
}
```

This condition will succeed when the string is empty because of the or statement. Note that empty is not the same as null:

```
if (Request.QueryString["fid"] != null || Request.QueryString["fid"].Length > 0)
{
    // "fid" could be empty, not null which causes the first condition to succeed.
    string t = Request.QueryString["fid"];
}
```

You'd want to use an && statement in the above:

```
if (Request.QueryString["fid"] != null && Request.QueryString["fid"].Trim().Length > 0)
{
    string t = Request.QueryString["fid"];
}
```